# Spark reading file from local gives InvalidInputException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Using Spark 2.2.0 installed by Homebrew on OSX High Sierra. I got into spark-shell and tried to read a local file like so:

```
val lines = sc.textFile("file:///Users/username/Documents/Notes/sampleFile")
val llist = lines.collect()
```

This gives me:

```
    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: 
Input path does not exist: file:/Users/bsj625/Documents/Notes/sampleFile
```

I've tried a bunch of variations, `file:/` and `file://`. I also tried running spark-shell in local mode like so:

```
spark-shell --master local
```

But I'm still getting the same error. Are there any environment variables I need to set? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Using just the file path (without file:/ or file://) doesn't work either

Comment: Is `/Users/username/Documents/Notes/sampleFile` a normal file or a directory?

Comment: It's a file. Just fixed it, that file didn't exist in that location, I was being an idiot. I moved it there and it works *facepalm*